# Javascript: client-side webservice with <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I'm trying to implement sort of client-side webservice client.

To get over the *same server policy*, i'm thinking of including the external page whose content I need to read via the `<script>` tag that can get cross-domain content. I have no control over the webservice being consumed, so i can't actually return javascript code (it's a simple html page returning "OK" or "KO" in the body).

It seems like I can't use src="text/html", only "text/javascript" is accepted and this yelds an obvious error as an html page can't be evaluated as javascript code.

Apart from that, how can I then read the loaded script's content? With Google Chrome's javascript console I can see that the page is loaded withing the script, only I don't know how to access it.

PS: I'm using jQuery, if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  If this worked, it would expose private (e.g. protected by cookies) user data to third-party sites.